# what does IN_NATIVE mean in jstack file ?

Tags: java, jstack

```
    Thread 10296: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(boolean, java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(java.net.ProtocolFamily, java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int) @bci=25, line=465 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int) @bci=6, line=457 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(java.net.SocketAddress) @bci=225, line=670 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.network.BlockingChannel.connect() @bci=135 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.SyncProducer.connect() @bci=21 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.SyncProducer.getOrMakeConnection() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(kafka.api.RequestOrResponse, boolean) @bci=13 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(kafka.api.TopicMetadataRequest) @bci=6 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(scala.collection.Set, scala.collection.Seq, kafka.producer.ProducerConfig, int, kafka.auth.KafkaUser) @bci=189 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(scala.collection.immutable.Set, int) @bci=24 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp() @bci=54 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(scala.Function2, scala.Function0) @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(kafka.utils.Logging, scala.Function0) @bci=12 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(scala.Function0) @bci=2 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(scala.collection.Seq) @bci=269 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.producer.Producer.send(scala.collection.Seq) @bci=45 (Interpreted frame)
 - kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(kafka.producer.KeyedMessage) @bci=21 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.tmri.cld.impl.kafka.SjKafkaClientUtil.sendMessage(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, byte[]) @bci=40, line=141 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.tmri.stream.handle.thread.w.SendLogDataThreadW.run() @bci=356, line=78 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1145 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
```

As show as above, I'm using jstack to get output and for debugging, I have googled and still not get the clear answer , can anybody tell me what does IN_NATIVE status mean in jstack output file ?

Comment: It means the exception occurred in native code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java threads: interpreting thread states of a running JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827543/java-threads-interpreting-thread-states-of-a-running-jvm)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At some point most code has to interact with the operating system and 'physical' hardware. Java does this through native code, and the JStack state of IN_NATIVE reflects this - it is running system "native" code rather than Java code (eg to write data to a file). See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for) for definitions of native code.

The states you see are VM dependent, but most likely you are running something with Hotspot or similar (OpenJDK, Oracle JDK etc) so the [following definitions](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/jvm/hotspot/runtime/JavaThreadState.java#JavaThreadState) should hold:

> - **UNINITIALIZED** - Should never happen (missing initialization)
> - **NEW** - Just starting up, i.e., in process of being initialized
> - **IN_NATIVE** - Running in native code
> - **IN_NATIVE_TRANS** - Corresponding transition state
> - **IN_VM** - Running in VM
> - **IN_VM_TRANS** - Corresponding transition state
> - **IN_JAVA** - Running in Java or in stub code
> - **BLOCKED** - Blocked in vm
> - **BLOCKED_TRANS** - Corresponding transition state

The _TRANS suffix is used to indicate threads are transitioning between states. Note the states IN_JAVA_TRANS and NEW_TRANS are not used, so I've excluded them from the above list.